# SELECT Queries and creating an infinate loop in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create multiple loops in PHP to select parent and child items. i have this code:

```
<?php
$counter = 0;
$sql="SELECT * from shop_categories where parent = '' order by name ASC ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $flag = 1;
    $current_parent_sequence = $result["sequence"];

    echo '<strong>'.$result["name"].'</strong><br>';

    while($flag == 1) {
        $counter++;

        $sql2="SELECT * from shop_categories where parent = '".$current_parent_sequence."' order by name ASC ";
        $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn);
        if(mysql_num_rows($rs2) > 0) {
            while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2)) {
                $current_parent_sequence = $result2["sequence"];

                echo $counter.' - '.$result2["name"].'<br>';
            }
        } else {
            $flag = 0;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

then i have this data in my table - http://postimg.org/image/o2p31xd1j/

so it should show the parent items and its child items and their child items and so on but its only showing:

```
Cat 1
1 - Sub Cat 1
1 - Sub Cat 2
Cat 2
Cat 3
4 - Sub Cat 1
```

Comment: Ok, so the problem with you're 2nd loop is that it's not checking for `sub sub items` until all the `sub items` have been checked, so by the time it comes to check for `sub sub items` it's on `Sub Cat 2` which doesn't have any child entries. A recursive function like @Apb suggested will help you check the table for each entry, rather than after the last entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below code. It might help you. You need create function which will call recursively.

```
function getChild($conn, $id) {
    $rs=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from test_tbl where parent = '$id' order by name ASC ");
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
        $current_parent_sequence = $result["sequence"];
        $parent = $result["parent"];
        echo "--" . $result["name"] . "<br>";
        if($parent != 0)
            getChild($conn, $current_parent_sequence);
    }
}

$rs=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from test_tbl where parent = '' order by name ASC ");
while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $current_parent_sequence = $result["sequence"];
    $parent = $result["parent"];
    echo $result["name"] . "<br>";
    getChild($conn, $current_parent_sequence);
}
```

Use `mysqli` as `mysql` is deprecated.

Comment: `mysql_*` has been removed, not deprecated.